# How to prepare solution: Sharepoint Group and Active Directory Group

Tags: active-directory, spgroup

How do I prepare a solution which does this:

When we add a new user to a Sharepoint Group, it should automatically add the user to an Active Directory Group. This should create two groups with the same users

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have the active directory group as the only member inside of a SharePoint group?

If you want to do it that way, it may have to be an Event Receiver for a Site using the GroupUserAdded event receiver, then you tie into adding that user to Active Directory like so:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find your user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "USERNAME");

    if(user != null)
    {
        // find the group in question
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "ADGROUPNAME");

        // if found....
        if (group != null)
        {
            // add user to group
            group.Members.Add(user);
            group.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nothing do. What the rights to AD should be ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom user interface for adding users to the SharePoint Group.

You can use `SPGroup` object for adding `SPUser` object into the group.

For manipulating Active Directory you can use `System.DirectorServices.AccountManagement` namespace. This has `GroupPrincipal` object

```
using (PrincipalContext p = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
{
    GroupPrincipal g= GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(p, "GroupName");
    g.Members.Add(p, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, UserId);
    g.Save();
}
```

Comment: And You have sample of It. More code. It should be on Sharepoint Page, or in asp.net page ?

Comment: In visual studio create sharepoint project -> Visual Webpart. Now create a webpart page and add the new web part.

Comment: And use GroupUserAdded Event Receiver ?

Comment: It showing me:  No principal matching the specified parameters was found.